# React Typescipt : UseState of Object Array only updates once in for loop

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-typescript

So I'm kind of new in typescript and trying something out. I want to randomize X quantity of players betweent X quantity of teams/groups to play a game with.( react native ts mobile app)

Weird behavior (atleast for me) the for loop that I'm using to update the teams in a state array does runs twice because I can see it in the logs and if I save my VS code document the second update in the state array does occus, but ofcourse I want it right the first time.

```
const [groupsWPlayer, setGroupsWPlayers] = useState<{title: string; players:string[]}[]>([]);
  const [groups, setGroups] = useState<string[]>(route.params?.groups);
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState<string[]>(route.params?.players);

  const AsignPlayersToGroupsAtRandom =  () => {
    setPlayers(arrayShuffle(players));
    for(let i =0; i <= groups.length-1; i++){
      console.log(i + " / " + groups.length);
      console.log("Group  =  " + groups[i]);
      setGroupsWPlayers([...groupsWPlayer, {title:groups[i], players:players}])
      }
  }
```

```
 {groupsWPlayer.map((group, index) => (
      <View key={index}>
        <Text> title = {group.title}</Text>
      <Text>{group.players}</Text>
      <Text>{groupsWPlayer.length}</Text>
      </View>
```

LOGS /
0 / 2
LOG  Group  =  Ok (group name)
LOG  1 / 2
LOG  Group  =  Niet oke (group name)

But it only renders the last group, not the first and the last, which i wanted to.

So for some reason the setGroupsWPlayers only runs once, doe somebody know why and cares to explain to me why? Even if it's a rookie mistake, i'm trying to learn. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to `setGroupsWPlayers` is not updating the actual `groupsWPlayer` immediately. The update will happen only on next render, so basically only the last call from the loop of `setGroupsWPlayers` is applied. `...groupsWPlayer` will always be the same here, so on first render in the for loop you will always get `[]` from it.

Add a temporal variable to store everything and call `setGroupsWPlayers` only once, outside of the loop.

```ts
const AsignPlayersToGroupsAtRandom = () => {
  setPlayers(arrayShuffle(players));
  const tmp: { title: string; players: string[] }[] = [];
  // or
  // const tmp: { title: string; players: string[] }[] = [...groupsWPlayer];
  for (let i = 0; i <= groups.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(i + " / " + groups.length);
    console.log("Group  =  " + groups[i]);
    tmp.push({ title: groups[i], players: players });
  }
  setGroupsWPlayers(tmp);
};
```

Note: If you also expect `players` to be updated immediately after `setPlayers(arrayShuffle(players));` - that will not happen, it will be updated on the next render only.

Comment: Thanks! It works with a temp variable, same with the setPlayers because it wouldn't update as you said. Thanks alot!